# PyDev throws Exception "Resourse does not exist" When re-opening a project

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, pydev

In my RCP app when I close and re-open a PyDev project, PyDev throws an exception on the console complaining that the project resource does not exist. Everything seems to work afterward, but of course I'd like to avoid showing a spurious exception to my users.

As best I can tell from navigating through the stack trace, PyDev's Content Provider expects the project resource to exist, and it does not. Perhaps I'm supposed to call some API in PyDev when I detect a project closing? Or is this a bug? I noticed the problem on version 5.1.2, but upgrading to the latest version (5.4.0) didn't resolve it.

EDIT:

I discovered that opening the project by `right-click on project -> Open Project` does not throw the exception. Only when opening the project by double-clicking on it. Double-click on an open project does not cause a problem, only double-click on a closed one. It seems the PyDev re-targeted action (PyOpenPythonFileAction) is being invoked before the framework has a chance to actually open the project.

EDIT2:

Actually it's stranger than that. The retargeted action that throws the exception is`PyOpenResourceAction` (but it's the `run()` implementation in superclass `PyOpenPythonFileAction` where it fails). The exception is thrown at line 110 on `if (viewer.isExpandable(container)) {`. The eclipse resource code there is checking the resource type against some flag bits, and I don;t know why it returns false. I put a guard to only check resources that are of type Project and the project exists and is open, and it still fails.

EDIT3:

In `PyOpenPythonFileAction`, Wrapping

```
if (viewer.isExpandable(container)) {
    viewer.setExpandedState(container, !viewer.getExpandedState(container));
}
```

in a `UIJob` and giving it a 500 msec delay seems to fix it.

Here is the console output with stack trace. The project that was closed and re-opened is named "site".

> !ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 1 1 2016-12-06 16:31:28.037
>   !MESSAGE Resource '/site' does not exist.
>   !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/site' does not exist.
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:335)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:209)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.hasNature(Project.java:521)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.getNature(Project.java:405)
>       at org.python.pydev.plugin.nature.PythonNature.getPythonNature(PythonNature.java:809)
>       at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.getChildrenForIResourceOrWorkingSet(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:611)
>       at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.getChildren(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:535)
>       at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonModelProvider.getChildren(PythonModelProvider.java:63)
>       at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.hasChildren(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:510)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.hasChildren(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:112)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.callNormalHasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:444)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.pipelineHasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.access$5(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:447)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$3.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:413)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.hasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:392)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.hasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:436)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2128)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.isExpandable(TreeViewer.java:538)
>       at org.python.pydev.navigator.actions.PyOpenPythonFileAction.run(PyOpenPythonFileAction.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:225)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$2.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:191)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:855)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:852)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1169)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:451)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5219)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4553)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4143)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
>       at my.package.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2016-12-06 16:31:28.095
>   !MESSAGE Resource '/site' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some reference to a non-existing `site` project somewhere in your project configuration (so, please inspect your `.project` and `.pydevproject` files in the workspace for such a project).

Comment: Thanks, but there's nothing in any .project file that seems to help when removing it. I tried removing all the system libraries, removing the interpreter itself, removing pydev nature from the project. Still I get a PyDev exception opening the project. The only way to make it not occur is to exclude PyDev Navigator Content from the Project Explorer in Customize View...Content tab. Of course that just removes Pyev capability from the explorer

Comment: Going through the stack trace, it looks like PyDev is trying to check if the project has PyDev nature, and the resource is inaccessible. The eclipse resource code there says that the project has to exist and be open for it to be accessiblle. But PyDev checks that before getting the nature (PythonBaseModelProvider lines 610-612), so I don;t know why access fails downstream. PyDev's Comman Navigator contribution seems to be checking for a project it used to know about, before that project opens. That's why I'm wondering if I need to de-register something somewhere.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. It looks like a DeleteParticipant I added is causing the problem. I had removed resource change listeners in my testing, but had overlooked the delete participant. I'll post later hopefully wit a specific description of what my code was doing that was causing the problem.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't the delete participant. I discovered more about the cause, which may be a PyDev bug. Please see my edit in the OP.